# How to get highest number from each list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm creating an arithmetic quiz for school students. At the menu, there is an option to view the scores of students. Once the user (a teacher) has chosen the class whose scores they want to view, they choose from one of three methods of sorting the chosen class' scores (which come from a text file) before they're outputted.

One of these methods is to take each student's highest score in the class and sort them alphabetically (from A-Z and according to each student's name). Each student has between 1 and 3 scores, which are stored in a list. The chosen class' scores are imported from the text file using JSON and are stored in the dictionary `scores`. In the dictionary, each student's name (first and last name, e.g. Isabella Morgan) is a key, and each key is attached to that student's list of scores.

I know that when I get each student's highest score, I can sort them alphabetically using sorted(). However, I can't figure out how to get the highest score (out of 10) from each student's list in the dictionary. Help with this would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's hard to understand your data structure without actually seeing the code

Comment: Hello, please provide a minimal example of what you tried so we can understand what's not working or what you're not successfully doing. SO is a QA site, not a place to get others do your job.

Comment: I believe that this is handled in previous questions -- whatever aspect is giving you trouble.  I recommend that you search the archives before you bother to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell without looking at the code, but from what you have asked for, and what I understood, this should direct you in some meaningful direction.

You can use `operator.itemgetter` for that:

```
import operator
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

And instead of building a new list in memory use `stats.iteritems()`. The key parameter to the `max()` function is a function that computes a key that is used to determine how to rank items.

Please note that if you were to have another key-value pair 'd': 3000 that this method will only return one of the two even though they both have the maximum value.

```
>>> import operator
>>> stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000}
>>> max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
'b'
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP is looking for.  In any case, this can be done easier using `max(stats, key=stats.get)`.

Comment: Also note that there is no `iteritems()` in Python 3 (which this question is about).